Measure to calculate running total per row in PowerBI Matrix
I have a table with three fields: Year, Period and Product.
Year    Period  Product
2020    1   A
2020    2   C
2020    3   A
2020    3   B
2020    4   C
2021    2   B
2021    3   C
2021    4   D
2021    1   A
2021    1   C
2022    3   A
2022    4   C
2022    1   C
2022    2   D
2022    1   A
2023    4   C
2023    3   B
2023    2   C
2023    4   B
2023    1   A
2024    1   A
2024    4   B
2024    3   C

I want to pivot it in a way that the y-axis is the year, the columns are the development periods and the values are the running total of the count of products.
The DAX code that I managed to get from "Generate Quick Measure" is
Count of Product running total in Period =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Sheet1'[Product]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Sheet1'[Period]),
        ISONORAFTER('Sheet1'[Period], MAX('Sheet1'[Period]), DESC)
    )
)


Unfortunately, it seems the running total being calculated is wrong. For instance, for 2020, I expect the values to be (table on the right): 1,2,4,5 instead of 1,2,3,3.
I'm unable to figure out what is going wrong and would appreciate some pointers. The goal is the get running total values per row/year.
A .pbix file with the minimal example from above: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13AJy85-yDKhIv09huwqzmyCpdWXicPn_/view?usp=sharing

Yes, thank you. Would your dax solution have to be modified if I want to add another column drill-down (say a month field to the y-axis)?

Ask a new question with all the details.


Try this:
Count of Product running total in Period = 
VAR x = MAX(Sheet1[Period])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Sheet1'[Product]), 
    Sheet1[Period] <= x
)

